# Prevention from XML injection in angularJS spring project

Tags: xml, security, code-injection, sanitization, html-sanitizing

I have designed a web based project using spring and hibernate & angularJs. In the security testing which I am completely unaware of I got that there are XML injection vulneribilities especially on GET requests.

There are some of  instances of this issue:

```
/MyProject/auditlog/getrecords [currentPage JSON parameter]
/MyProject/auditlog/getrecords [fromDate JSON parameter]
/MyProject/auditlog/getrecords [isApp JSON parameter]
```

So, I think think it can be solved at front-end angular side?

And how can I fix this security bug. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be conflating a couple of issues here. There is XML Injection (would happen in your server code) and AngularJS Injection (Template Injection) which would occur if you are writing data into the AngularJS template server side, which you should never do.

If you are using JSON I'm not really sure where the XML injection would come into play unless you are using the JSON values server side to construct some kind of XML Document.

If it is an injection into AngularJS resulting in Cross Site Scripting (XSS) of some sort, you are probably using AngularJS inappropriately.

With more information about the issue found, I could be more specific. Can you provide more information?